# Sass to CSS output as single line

Tags: css, sass

Trying to change multiline output from Sass to CSS conversion to single line output.

Sass:

```
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
  
  span {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

CSS multi-line (Sass default):

```
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}

p span {
  color: blue;
}
```

CSS single-line:

```
p { font-size: 18px; color: red; } p span { color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `style=compressed` flag in the CLI to indicate that it should be output onto single line.

Normal usage:

```
$ sass style.scss
```

With `style=compressed` flag:

```
$ sass --style=compressed style.scss
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#style